# Is there a dashboard widget for Microsoft Outlook/Exchange calendar?

Tags: calendar, dashboard-widget, ms-office

Does there exist a dashboard widget which displays my Outlook/Entourage and Exchange calendar?

Answer (score 4):

There are no widgets for OSX for use with Outlook, there are calendar widgets for iCal or Google Calendars, that can be [downloaded here](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/) but you will need to route all your calendars through iCal or Google calendars instead of Outlook and you probably won't want to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Fantastical works with Outlook.
http://flexibits.com/fantastical

Comment: How does this serve as a dashboard widget?

Comment: It also doesn't work with outlook -- it works with Exchange, and our corp (unfortunately) only allows outlook to connect to our exchange server.